# Send Data To specific Clients Via WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created Client-Server Texas Holdem Game using WCF technology.
assuming a client waits for an opponent in order to start playing then when another player joins the room the server deals the cards. 
How do I send the cards to the corresponded Clients using WCF service?
I implemented Callback interface and I save a list of players's callback using

```
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<CallbacksInterfaceName>();
```

I don't want to work via TCP Socket communication so I don't have to keep IP addresses in DB table.

Thanks!

Comment: And storing the callbacks doesn't work?

Comment: Is this using a stable WCF connection or setup/teardown with each message.  If you are doing stable then you can simplely store the callback in process and assigned it a player id and game id as the same player might be in multiple games at the same time.